# Join pandas dataframes based on different conditions

Tags: python, sql, pandas, join, merge

I´m using Pandas in Python and I'd like to join 2 dataframes. My first dataframe is:

| id | var | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABCD | 2019-01-01 |
| 1 | ABCD | 2017-06-01 |
| 1 | ABCD | 2016-06-01 |
| 2 | ABCD | 2016-01-01 |

The dataframe I want to join is:

| var | date |
| --- | --- |
| ABCD | 2019-01-01 |
| ABCD | 2017-06-01 |
| FJKL | 2016-06-01 |
| ABCD | 2016-01-01 |

I want to join the firt dataframe by `var` and `date` but the condition is that the date of the second dataframe has to be smaller than the first. If I were in sql I would do:

```
   select 
   a.*,
   b.* 
   from fisrt_data a 
   join second_data b on a.var = b.var and a.date > b.date
```

Any ideas to implement with pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `merge` and `query`:

```
(df1.merge(df2, on=['var'], suffixes=['_a','_b'])
    .query('date_a > date_b')
)
```

Output:

```
   id    var       date_a      date_b
1    1  ABCD   2019-01-01  2017-06-01
2    1  ABCD   2019-01-01  2016-01-01
5    1  ABCD   2017-06-01  2016-01-01
8    1  ABCD   2016-06-01  2016-01-01
```

Comment: also join and filter() ?

Comment: @eshirvana I'm not following. `filter()` only filter the column names, not the data. `query` filters the data.

Comment: i was wondering if we can get the same result by  join() and filter()? (I'm learning pandas)

Comment: @eshirvana then no, the reason is as stated in my other comment :-).

Comment: well the documentation for `filter()` says `Subset the dataframe rows or columns according to the specified index labels.` , so I was assuming that should work for filtering rows

Comment: It also says in the second paragraph: *Note that this routine does not filter a dataframe on its contents. The filter is applied to the labels of the index.*, so no :-).